# How to handle information of certificate in a PEM file

Tags: shell, certificate, pem

I exported certificates from keychain to a PEM file. I want to handle information of each certificate in a loop by writing a shell-script file.

When I run this command to check the file:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile [file name here].pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text | grep -E '(Subject:|Not After)'
```

All certificates's information will be printed. But when I run this command:

```
openssl x509 -in certs.pem -text
```

It only shows information of the first certificate in the file. I tried to get count of certificate in the PEM file with a shell, it returned 1.

```
#! /bin/bash
   i=0;
   for cert in [PEM file path]; do 
   let "t=$i + 1";
   echo $t;
   done
```

Could anyone help me to handle certificates in PEM file?. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the certificates are separated by the BEGIN/END-comments. You could split the PEM-string like this:

```sh
IN="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----..."
CERTS=( $(IFS="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" echo "$IN") )
echo ${CERTS[0]}
echo ${CERTS[1]}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've dealt with this issue by this way.

Comment: Happy to hear! Would you mark the answer as correct then?